# Replace sentence on page refresh

Tags: jquery

Can somebody point me in the right direction so I can change a sentence on page refresh.

For example.

On document ready I would have

"Hello my friend how are you"

Then when the use refreshes the page

"Hello dude"

I've looked at:

```
<div>
      <blockquote class="quote key"><span>quote1</span><p class="exec">person 1</p></blockquote>
      <img src="image1.jpg">
   </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var myQuotes = new Array(); 
      myQuotes[0] = "Hello my friend"; 
      myQuotes[1] = "Hey Dude"; 
      myQuotes[2] = "Hi"; 

var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length); 

   });
});
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try

**HTML**

```
 <div>
      <span class='message'></span>
      <blockquote class="quote key">
           <span>quote1</span>
           <p class="exec">person 1</p>
       </blockquote>
      <img src="image1.jpg">
</div>​​​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var myQuotes = new Array(); 
      myQuotes[0] = "Hello my friend"; 
      myQuotes[1] = "Hey Dude"; 
      myQuotes[2] = "Hi"; 

      var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length); 
      $(".message").text( myQuotes[myRandom ] );

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pGMZw/

​

Comment: This is random, though. With a poor distribution, it could say "Hello my friend" every single time. I think the OP wants it to cycle, or just change once.

Comment: @Eric  I'm guessing OP will be happy to get this far..placing the content in DOM

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cookies for this requirement. There is a [cookies plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for jquery that makes deal with cookies easier.